# Parallel Python module using other server

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parallel-python

I'm using parallel python to do some number crunching on several computers. Everything was working fine till I thought it would be nice to include some classes.

Here is the code for submitting the jobs:

```
for i in xrange(n_cpus):
    jobs.append(job_server.submit(self.fcalc_rs_rp, (ch_lambdas[i], thetas, ch_n_arr[i]), (), ("import numpy as np", "from SimulationOO import *")))
```

It works perfectly fine on a single computer (also uses all cores, so fine), but if I try to use another server the calculations never stop.

The problem is that the server has no cpu load, because it can't load `from SimulationOO import *` since the file doesn't exist on the server.

One workaround would be to put the method **`.fcalc_rs_rp()`** out of the class and make it a function but actually I want to have the function inside a class and maybe you have a good idea?

If I try to not use the `from SimulationOO import *` part and instead define all functions needed as depfuncs, it gives the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Layer'` where `Layer` is one of the classes I'm using.

Do you have any advice, how I could get this working?

Thank you

Comment: 1. Should `the file doesn't exist on this computer` be `the file does not exist on the server` ? 2. Which job-submitter-package do you use?

Comment: Yes, on the server. I'm using parallel python (http://www.parallelpython.com)